# Best practises using JWT for authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt

I have read a lot of articles related to JWT (JSON web token) use for authentication and got really confused, since everyone has a different opinion on what is a secure way of using them. By saying secure I mean handling logouts and password changes. Also, what data should not be saved in JWT payload.

My question - Are there any industry standards when using JWT for Auth, if yes what are they? If not, is it secure to save password hash and logout date in JWT to handle logouts and password changes, if not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any industry standards when using JWT for auth, if yes what are they?

First of all, access tokens (as any type of sensitive information) must only be sent over a secure connection.

On my understanding, you want the ability to revoke the tokens when some sort of event occurs. In this case, you should consider keeping the track of tokens somewhere in your server.

To achieve it, you could assign a unique identifier to each token and then store such identifier in your server. When validating the token, besides checking the signature and the expiration date, you must also check whether the token identifier is whitelisted.

And, to assign a unique identifier to each token, you can use the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim:

> [**4.1.7.  "jti" (JWT ID) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7)
>
> The `jti` (JWT ID) claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT. The identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that there is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally assigned to a different data object; if the application uses multiple issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values produced by different issuers as well.  The `jti` claim can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed.  The `jti` value is a case-sensitive string.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

---

> If not, is it secure to save password hash and logout date in JWT to handle logouts and password changes, if not what are the alternatives?

If your JWT is a JWS, you shouldn't put any information that is considered sensitive in the payload.